# Xcode 5: unable to generate Developer ID Distribution

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I'm developing an OS X App, that I would like to sign with a *Developer Id*, making it able to run on Macs with *Gatekeeper*. My Apple ID is Mac Developer Program administrator. From within Xcode (version 5.0.2) I try to generate a *Developer ID Distribution* but it gives me this error:

[image: Developer ID Distribution error]

In `Console.app` is see this error message:

> Team member 'ID***' is not authorized to perform the requested operation

I've checked that the above member ID match my profile in *Member Center*. Why do I get this error when my account is both iOS, Mac and Safari program admin. Is it possible to generate this *Developer ID Distribution* from the *Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles* section on Apple Developer?

Comment: I think you need to be an agent for that.

Comment: I think you are right. Under *Requesting Signing Identities* it says: "Only a team agent can create a Developer ID certificate.". https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW6

Comment: Yup, I hade the same problem... Cool if I add that as an answer?

Comment: You are welcome. I'm not the Team Agent, so I have to wait until tomorrow to verify this.

Comment: I really don't need to. Was just thinking that it might help other... But I can answer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Team Agents can do that, which is pretty strange when I think about it.

Comment: I've verified that only the Team Agent is able to generate these certificates. Strange.

Comment: Logging in using my Team Agent account, from within Lion + Safari, I can't create Developer ID using Apple Developer website. `Unexpected error` or the like.  Curious that it cause by an old system being use, my team agent then transfer his role to me. Issuing Developer ID certificate request from within Xcode 6.1 still failed: `An error occurred while requesting a certificate`. Now I am not sure what to do... Heck, maybe I will just have to use a better internet connection then. Any idea?